# Algorithm in C - playing with numbers - number with 3 in units place

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers

I came across this question in an interview. 
Any number with 3 in its units position has at least one multiple containing all ones. For instance, a multiple of 3 is 111, a multiple of 13 is 111111. Given a number ending in 3, I was asked the best method to find its multiple containing all 1's.
Now a straightforward approach is possible, where you do not consider space issues but as the number grows, and sometimes even if it doesn't, an **int** (or a **long int** at that!) in C cannot hold that multiple.
What is the optimal way to implement such an algorithm in C?

Comment: Yeah sorry about the mis-typing. Edited.

Comment: How about: a multiple of 133?

Comment: eighteen ones : 111111111111111111

Comment: In fact, it's not necessary to use big number division or multiplication...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Incorporating Ante's observations and making the answer community wiki.

As usual in this type of problems, coding any working brute-force algorithm is relatively easy, but the more math. you do with pencil and paper, the better (faster) algorithm you can get.

Let's use a shorthand notation: let M(i) mean 1111...1 (i ones).

Given a number n (let's say n = 23), you want to find a number m such that M(m) is divisible by n.  A straightforward approach is to check 1, 11, 111, 1111, ... until we find a number divisible by n.  Note: there might exist a [closed-form solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for finding m given n, so this approach is not necessarily optimal.

When iterating over M(1), M(2), M(3), ..., the interesting part is, obviously, how to check whether a given number is divisible by n.  You could implement [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), but [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) is slow.  Instead, consider the following:

Assume that you already know, from previous iterations, the value of `M(i) mod n`.  If `M(i) mod n = 0`, then you're done (`M(i)` is the answer), so let's assume it's not.  You want to find `M(i+1) mod n`.  Since `M(i+1) = 10 * M(i) + 1`, you can easily calculate `M(i+1) mod n`, as it's `(10 * (M(i) mod n) + 1) mod n`.  This can be calculated using fixed-precision arithmetic even for large values of n.

Here's a function which calculates the smallest number of ones which are divisible by n (translated to C from Ante's Python answer):

```
int ones(int n) {
        int i, m = 1;
        /* Loop invariant: m = M(i) mod n, assuming n > 1 */
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                if (m == 0)
                        return i;  /* Solution found */
                m = (10*m + 1) % n;
        }
        return -1;  /* No solution */
}
```

Comment: I've just implemented long division before I saw your post, and found out that the multiple of 23 is 1111111111111111111111. But your last pharagraph seems to me very interesting, need to check it out

Comment: +1 I didn't see your answer before writting mine , but that's it, the solution is the minimum number of i such that the sum of (10^i mod n) is a multiple of n

Comment: `M(i+1) = 10*M(i) + 1`, there is no need for `10^i mod n` sequence.

Comment: @Ante Great!  Your remark yields a faster and more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you explain why m is initialized to 1 and why I jterates until n?

Comment: @DanielKobe `m` is initialized to `1` because `i` is initially `1` and we have the invariant `m = M(i) mod n`. `i` iterates until `n` because there are at most `n` different values of `m` and they loop in a cycle of length not greater than `n` (this is because each next value of `m` is a function of the previous one). So if we cannot find `m = 0` among the first `n` values, we will never find it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to consider this question in the 'big number' way. Just take a paper, do the multiplication by hand, and soon you'll find the best answer:)

**First**, let's consider the units' digit of the result of **3x**

```
 x  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

3x  0 3 6 9 2 5 8 1 4 7
```

Thus, the relationship is:

```
what we want 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 multiplier  0 7 4 1 8 5 2 9 6 3
```

**Second**, do the multiplication, and don't save unnecessary numbers. Take 13 for example, to generate a '1', we have to choose the multiplier 7, so

```
13 * 7 = 91
```

well, save '9', now what we faces is 9. We have to choose multiplier[(11-9)%10]:

```
13 * 4 = 52, 52 + 9 = 61
```

Go on! Save '6'. Choose multiplier[(11-6)%10]

```
13 * 5 = 65, 65 + 6 = 71
```

Save '7'. Choose multiplier[(11-7)%10]

```
13 * 8 = 104, 104 + 7 = 111
```

Save '11'. Choose multiplier[(11-11)%10]

```
13 * 0 = 0, 0 + 11 = 11
```

Save '1'. Choose multiplier[(11-1)%10]

```
13 * 0 = 0, 0 + 1 = 1
```

Save '0'. WOW~! When you see '0', the algorithm ends!

**Finally**, if you print a '1' for one step above, here you will get a '1' string answer.

Comment: Only integers are used and multiplication --- great solution!

Answer (score 3):

Like Bolo's solution with simpler equality `M(i+1) = 10*M(i) + 1`. Here is python version:

```
def ones( n ):
  i = m = 1
  while i <= n:
    if m == 0:
      return i
    m = ( ( 10 * m ) + 1 ) % n
    i += 1
  return None
```

Comment: Excellent!  Unless there's a closed-form formula, that is the fastest (and very elegant) algorithm.  I like how you've avoided infinite loops, too.

Comment: @Bolo sequence M(i) can have at most n different values, so there is no need to search further.

Comment: @Ante Yes, I understand.  As I said, it's a very nice observation!

Comment: m%n in the 4th line is unnecessary since you are already doing it in line 7 and the value of m is not changing after that, so you can directly check  m==0.

Answer (score 2):

The multiple of 23 is 1111111111111111111111

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main () {
        unsigned int ones = 1;
        double result, by = 23, dividend = 1;
        while (dividend) {
            result = dividend / by;
                if (result < 1) {
                    dividend = dividend * 10 + 1;
                        ++ones;
                } else {
                    dividend -= by * (int)result;
                }
        }
        while (ones--) {
            printf("1");
        }
        printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no an infinite loop check, so it must be added, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone is looking for a solution in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input = 55333;
    int minAllOnesNum = 1;
    int nextAllOnesNum= minAllOnesNum;  

    int numberof1s=1;
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        count++;

        if(nextAllOnesNum%input == 0 ) 
        {
            break;  
        }

        nextAllOnesNum = nextAllOnesNum*10 + 1;

        if(nextAllOnesNum>=input) {
            nextAllOnesNum%=input;
        }
        numberof1s++;
    }


    System.out.println("count : " + count);

    for(int i=1; i<=numberof1s; i++) {
        System.out.print("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.