# Numbers ending in 3 have at least one multiple having all ones

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Hi Here is a Q that was asked in Adobe Interview.

> Numbers ending in 3 have at least one multiple having all ones.  for
> eg., 3 and 13 have amultiples like 111 and 111111 respectively. Given
> such  a no. , find the smallest such multiple of that number. The
> multiple can  exceed the range of int, long. You cannot use any
> complex data structure.

Can you provide me with an efficient solution

Comment: An explanatory answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130063).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm in C - playing with numbers - number with 3 in units place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129855/algorithm-in-c-playing-with-numbers-number-with-3-in-units-place)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

got the answer now :)

```
int count=1, rem=1; 
while(rem)
{
 rem= (rem*10+1)%n; count++;
} 
 while(count--){ cout<<"1";}
```

Comment: you just said the multiple could exceed integer range.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The question does not exclude integers or long integers - it merely states that a solution may exceed the range of such. It excludes using complex data structures. It does not exclude using modular arithmetic and observations of the relation between `x mod 3` and `(x*10+1) mod 3` to calculate a string of characters that represent an appropriate multiple without actually calculating such multiple...

Comment: @Aravind yes it is count is the no of times 1 is occuring in the multiple while loop is printing that number

Comment: It's a beautiful solution! Could you please elaborate a little on how it uses modular arithmetic?

Comment: I think it's not a good answer for a job interview or homework. Use Fermat's little theorem is the way to go.

Comment: as @akaHuman is commenting some code must does not says to much why this is the best solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt to do it more efficiently that trying 1, 11, 111, 111.. Could this pay off. Is there a more elegant answer better than trying numbers one at a time?

Write the numbers 1, 11, 111, ... as (10^k - 1) / 9, where the division is known to be exact. Given a target number in the form 10x+3 we want to find the smallest k solving (10^k - 1) / 9 = Y(10x + 3) where Y is an integer. Look for small solutions of 10^k = 1 mod 9(10x + 3). This is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm except that arithmetic mod 9(10x + 3) does not necessarily form a group - however the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step algorithm should still apply and could be used to search steadily increasing ranges of k, instead of searching possible values of k one at a time.

Comment: I do think this is the actual solution not others. But just wanted to understand how is it efficient than trying 1,11,111 etc ? We are calculating 10^k mod A (assume A=9(10x+3)) every iteration, with increasing k, right? What if the variable storing 10^k overflows and the result is very big? Is this the optimum method interviewer expects using congruent properties? -Thanks.. I'm just curious.

Comment: The arithmetic required is mod 9(10x + 3) and if this overflows you are out of luck unless you switch to multiple precision, but that happens some time after 10^k overflows. The efficiency follows from the fact that the baby-step/giant-step algorithm allows you to search a range of N possibilities in time O(sqrt(N))

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        long long n;
        cin>>n;
        long long cur = 1;
        while(cur%n!=0){
            cur = cur*10+1;
        }
        cout<<cur<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `long long` to evade to `exceed the range of int, long` is poor. Did you try to understand _how_ other solutions don't need numbers (much) greater than the number given?

Answer (score 0):

Solution independent of output size:

```
public String ones(int n)
 {
    int i, m = 1;
    String num="1";

     for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
              if (m == 0)
              return num;
             /* Solution found */
             num=num+"1";
            m = (10*m + 1) % n;
    }
    return null;  /* No solution */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Solution in Java, here it is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input = 13; // this can be any number ending with 3
    int minAllOnesNum = 1;
    int nextAllOnesNum= minAllOnesNum;  

    int numberof1s=1;
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        count++;

        if(nextAllOnesNum%input == 0 ) 
        {
            break;  
        }

        nextAllOnesNum = nextAllOnesNum*10 + 1;

        if(nextAllOnesNum>=input) {
            nextAllOnesNum%=input;
        }
        numberof1s++;
    }


    System.out.println("Number of iterations : " + count);

    for(int i=1; i<=numberof1s; i++) {
        System.out.print("1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Solution in Java, here it is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int input = 55333;
    int minAllOnesNum = 1;
    int nextAllOnesNum= minAllOnesNum;  

    int numberof1s=1;
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        count++;

        if(nextAllOnesNum%input == 0 ) 
        {
            break;  
        }

        nextAllOnesNum = nextAllOnesNum*10 + 1;

        if(nextAllOnesNum>=input) {
            nextAllOnesNum%=input;
        }
        numberof1s++;
    }


    System.out.println("Number of Iterations: " + count);

    for(int i=1; i<=numberof1s; i++) {
        System.out.print("1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int findOnes(int num){
    int i = 1   ;
    int power = 0;
    while (i % num != 0){
        i = (i * (10^power)) + 1;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: What language? Did you mean to XOR `10` with `power`?